# WordPress site under subdirectory not working

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks

I have 2 WordPress websites, one is in the root directory and another is under /shop subdirectory, now when I am visiting any pages of /shop I am getting page not found error. I have tried Wordpres default .htaccess with `RewriteBase /shop` but not working, can anyone please guide me what to do?

For example, this URL working fine,

```
domain.com/example-page
```

But when I try to visit /shop URL then I am getting not found error.

```
domain.com/shop/example-product-page
```

Both WordPress sites have followed the basic installation process.

I found the solution if anyone else facing same issue then just edit htaccess and try like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /shop/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /shop/index.php [L]
```

Comment: There isn't enough information for us to work out what might be going wrong. We don't know anything about your WP setup so we are unable to help. You will need to investigate it yourself to narrow it down.

Comment: I have added some more info,

Comment: OK, Don't mind I found how to fix, I just used RewriteRule . /shop/index.php [L] and its working now